# Failed to extract _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd : decompression resulted in return code -1

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, huggingface-transformers

I have converted my Python script into an executable (.exe) using a .spec file. The Python project was developed in a virtual environment and runs successfully when launched. One of the modules I have installed is sklearn and the transformers module. However, I faced significant difficulties when trying to run the .exe file, apparently due to these modules. Now, when I launch the .exe, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to extract _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd : decompression resulted in return code -1!
```

and after a second run its :

```
Failed to extract VCOMP140.DLL : decompression resulted in return code -1!
```

Here is my .spec file, and I have also provided the imports from my two Python files, "run" and "core_2". Honestly, I am having trouble identifying the root cause of the issue. I opted to use a .spec file because I noticed that most errors could be resolved with modifications here, and it seemed simpler than using auto-py-to-exe.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = [("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/BT42.xlsx","."),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/finetuned_camembert/*", "finetuned_camembert"),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/donnees_embeddings.npy","."),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/donnees_gagnanteslabels.xlsx","."),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/données_gagnants_labels_sans_autres.xlsx","."),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/données_test.xlsx","."),
    ("C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso/Traitement BPU 2.1/exemple.png",".")]
datas += copy_metadata('tqdm')
datas += copy_metadata('transformers')
datas += copy_metadata('regex')
datas += copy_metadata('sacremoses') 
datas += copy_metadata('requests')
datas += copy_metadata('packaging')
datas += copy_metadata('filelock')
datas += copy_metadata('numpy')
datas += copy_metadata('tokenizers')
datas += copy_metadata('importlib_metadata')
datas += copy_metadata('tensorflow')
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=["C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive/Bureau/Projet_perso"],
         binaries=[("C:/Users/pierr/Documents/Lib/site-packages/torch/lib/torch_python.dll", "."),
                   ("C:/Users/pierr/Documents/Lib/site-packages/torch/lib/torch_cpu.dll", "."),
                   ("C:/Users/pierr/Documents/Lib/site-packages/torch/lib/c10.dll", "."),
                   ("C:/Users/pierr/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/local-packages/Python39/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd", ".")],
             datas=datas,
             hiddenimports=["scikit-learn", "tqdm", "transformers"],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='main',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=False , icon='C:/Users/pierr/Downloads/logo_sef.ico')`
```

IMPORT :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from tkinter import messagebox

import os
import webbrowser
import core_2 as traitement
```

IMPORT 2 :

```
import os
import sys

import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_to_tuple
import numpy as np
import torch
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from transformers import CamembertTokenizer, CamembertModel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import shutil
```

What I want is to allow a user who doesn't use Python to be able to run my code by accessing the tkinter user interface thanks to the .exe

Comment: From my experience, PyInstaller commonly has issues installing complex libs like `tensorflow` and `transformers`. I have a couple of questions. Is all of your tooling/libs up to date (pyinstaller, tensorflow, transformer, etc). And have you tried any other packing tool like `cs_Freeze` or `py2exe`? And if so, can you post the result so I can compare it with `pyinstaller`?